# Issue with calling Azure stored procedure using external tables from C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, external-tables

I have a stored procedure in one of my Azure databases that links to external tables from another database.

If I run this stored procedure in the DB it runs fine, returning the data I expect. If I call the same stored procedure with the same input parameters from C# code, it is running, but returning null data at the points where the data is fetched from the external tables.

I have checked my user has permission to access the external tables...

Would anyone have any ideas what else I can check?

Thanks,

private void UpdateTABLEX(int ID)
{

```
        string CSQuery = "EXEC [stg].[UpdateTableX_Proc] @ID";

        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(DB1))
        {
            try
            {
                cn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CSQuery, cn))
                {

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                Refresh();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Error error = new Error(e.ToString(), "TableX Issue");
                error.LogError();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Could you share the C# code you are using to run the stored proc? That will help greatly in trying to repro the issue. My first thought is to check whether the parameters are actually being sent to the database properly. I've also seen instances where there was an error causing the null result, but it was being hidden in a try/catch block.

Comment: Thanks for replying, have added the c# code

Comment: Is this *procedure* supposed to return data? In that case you don't want to do `ExecuteNonQuery` but something like `ExecuteScalar`/`ExecuteReader`. If the procedure returns no data but is instead intended to do an update and the `Refresh` method is supposed to get the new data, confirm that you are actually doing the same thing that way as when you're running things manually. Also, [don't use `AddWithValue`](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: Just checking in @Alison. Did Jeroen's response resolve your question?

Comment: @Alison is the error solved now?